# HTML Object tag remove scrollbar overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am trying to apply the `overflow` property to an `<object/>` element. Is this possible?

An example of the issue is here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4Zvc/3/). In Chrome, it seems the overflow is ignored. How can I fix this?

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <object id="my-object" data="http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1.txt"></object>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#my-object {
    height : 500px;
    width : 300px;
    overflow : hidden;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the `object` element.

Comment: I tried with iframe too. But it has a different issue of half content. [update JSFiddle with scrolling="no" in iframe](http://jsfiddle.net/M4Zvc/6/)

Comment: @ManuKMohan Did you end up solving this issue?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I am using iframe now. Setting it a fixed height and scroll no. I cant do anything much more.

Answer (score 1):

Data objects like `<object>` do not have an overflow property. You can check this yourself by going into your browser's inspector, going to the `obj#my-object` properties and looking for `overflow` (it's not there)

As a result, hide the scrollbar by putting it in a container and making the parent a little smaller than the child by about 20px. You can then use use another element who has the same width and height of the text element and overlay it to prevent the scroll.  All in all, it [looks like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/M4Zvc/8/)

```
<body scroll="no">
    <div class='container'>
        <object id="my-object" data="http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1.txt">
        </object>
        <div class='preventScroll'></div>
    </div>
</body>

.container { 
    width:300px; height:500px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    position:relative; 
}
.preventScroll { 
    width:100%; height:100%; 
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0; 
}
#my-object {
    height: 100%;
    width: 320px;
    position:relative;
}
```

With that being said, I would recommend using the more modern `<iframe>` instead

Comment: I see this example works just like [iframe demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M4Zvc/6/). How will we see the whole content inside? I mean to auto adjust the height and width according to the embedded content.

Comment: If you want to see the whole content then `overflow:hidden` is not looking for... You'd just set the height to show all of it or else leave it with scroll bars. Your question is how to hide everything else

Answer (score 0):

```
#object {
    height : 500px;
    width : 300px;
    overflow : hidden;
}
```

Remove quotes around `hidden`

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the keyword object. Change it to

```
<body scroll="no">
    <object id="mycontent" data="http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1.txt">
    </object>
</body>


#mycontent {
    height : 500px;
    width : 300px;
    overflow : hidden;
}
```

Comment: If you notice, the object has ID of **object**

Comment: @user3653148 Did you not read the question? OP is trying to hide overflow.